# Java - JSch - Getting exit status 123. What does it mean?

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch, exit-code

Running command to retrieve a data from files on remote server (code bellow).
On closing channel sometimes receiving exit code 123.

Found in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

> ERROR_INVALID_NAME 123 (0x7B)
> The filename, directory name, or volume
> label syntax is incorrect.

But I am not sure it is the same error code meaning.
Please, advise

Code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session = jsch.getSession(BillingUser, BillingHost, 22);
session.setPassword(BillingPassword);
session.setConfig(config);     
session.connect();                       
channel = session.openChannel("exec");          
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
channel.setInputStream(null);
(ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.out);
InputStream inputStream = channel.getInputStream();
InputStream errStream = channel.getExtInputStream();
channel.connect();
if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
    //saving output here
}
inputStream.close();
errStream.close();
if (channel.isClosed()) {
    if (channel.getExitStatus() != 0){
        //printing here exitStatus value
    }
}
```

Connecting to Linux. Running command like:

```sh
find filesPath -type f -name "meAutomation,meAutomation*"| xargs egrep -r -i "20171031(04|03).*,meAutomation,meAutomation,.*,mEnterprise.*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit code is system specific.

You are probably connecting to *nix system. So you may want to read answers to
[Got exit code 123 in find + xargs grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26540813/850848).

> 123 means "any invocation exited with a non-zero status".

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). For the correct (and secure) approach, see: [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)*

Comment: Thanks, I believe it is it. Just left to understand what in my command can cause non-zero status :) I'm afraid this is the answer : The exit code will still be 123 if there are grep invocations which return zero matches