# Does tar exit code 123 always mean empty archive?

Tags: linux, tar, return-code

```
[root@my-pc: ]# printf "" | xargs tar czf ./foo.tgz
tar: empty archive
[root@my-pc: ]# echo $?
123
[root@my-pc: ]#
```

The tar man page only documents return codes `0`, `1`, and `2` but explains further:

> If a subprocess that had been invoked by tar exited with a nonzero
>   exit code, tar itself exits with that code as well.  This can happen,
>   for example, if a compression option (e.g. -z) was used and the
>   external compressor program failed.  Another example is rmt failure
>   during backup to a remote device.

So I assume this return code "`123`" comes from some invoked subprocess.

**Question**: Does tar exit code 123 always mean empty archive? (what subprocess returns this code?)

**What I have tried**:

1) The only thing I could think of was to `strace` this, but I'm not experienced enough with it to tell if its output reveals the answer to my question.

```
[root@my-pc: ]# printf "" | xargs strace tar czf ./foo.tgz 2>&1 | grep -w 123
```

Is the above the correct way to run `strace` on `tar`? In any case, the command had no output.

I can include the output of the above without the final `grep` if relevant, but I'm excluding it for now because it's long, and it's not clear to me that it's necessarily useful

2) Searched SO, the closest hit I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540813/got-exit-code-123-in-find-xargs-grep), but I'm not sure that that's relevant (not clear to me that `find`/`xargs` is involved in the return code of "`123`")

Comment: You'll need the `-f` argument to strace to follow into subprocesses.

Comment: (and yes, as implied by the message, using `-z` causes `gzip` to run. Can you still get that exit status with just `cf` instead of `czf`? If not, that implies *very* strongly that you should be narrowing your focus to gzip)

Comment: BTW, `xargs tar` is probably a bad idea in general. What happens if you have more filenames than `xargs` can put onto a single `tar` command's command-line argument list? (Answer: It runs `tar` a *second* time, and overwrites the output file written by the first invocation). `tar` can take a list of files on stdin itself; there's no reason to couple it with `xargs`, and plenty of reason not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man xargs`:

```
EXIT STATUS
       xargs exits with the following status:
       0 if it succeeds
       123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125
       124 if the command exited with status 255
       125 if the command is killed by a signal
       126 if the command cannot be run
       127 if the command is not found
       1 if some other error occurred.
```

Thus, *any* nonzero exit status from `tar` will cause `xargs tar` to use status `123`.